# Can anybody explain this Java Mergesort behavior interpretation?

Tags: java, algorithm, mergesort

I have this code and I'm trying to understand its tricky behavior, and yes the whole program works I just can't understand its tricky behavior:

```
private static void mergesort(int data[], int low, int high)
{
    int m;  // Midpoint in the array

    if (low < high)
    {
        // Compute sizes of the two halves
        // Rounding to least significant value (next lower integer, implicit casting)
        m = (low + high) / 2 ;
        mergesort(data, low, m);      // Sort data[first] through data[first+n1-1]
        mergesort(data, m+1, high); // Sort data[first+n1] to the end Porque aumenta high sólo si los parametros iniciales son (data, 0, 0)
        merge(data, low, high, m);
    }       
}
```

Let's say I have a list data: `{5, 3, 1, 2, 4}`

If I step into monitoring the parameters `(data[], low, high)` and the sub product `m` (`low + high /2`), we have a recursive call for `mergesort` in particular this instruction after the if condition:

```
mergesort(data, low, m);
```

I get:

```
STEP  1 2 3 4
low   0 0 0 0
high  4 2 1 0
mid   2 1 0 0
```

As you can see so far so good (it makes sense to me) but we have the condition:

```
 if (low < high)
```

which is not true for `low = 0` and `high = 0`, it exits the if (there is no else) and return to where the function was called to execute another batch of another instruction:

```
merge(data, low, high, m);
```

but according to the debugger it is called with `low = 0`, `high = 1`, `m = 0`. Why is it called with these arguments? How did `high` get incremented?

Answer (score 0):

High is not incremented.  With each recursive call, high is halved.  4, 2, 1, 0.
It's called in that way to split the list up into it smallest possible portions in order to merge them.
It continues recurring until (for this segment of the code) low and high are the same.

Answer (score 0):

`low` and `high` are *local variables*. That means that they are visible only to the function they are created in (or passed to). When a particular call to `mergesort` exits, the `high` `low` and `m` that it used are simply discarded (they do not affect the parent's `low`, `high`, or `m`.

In the debugger if you watch a call to `mergesort` with arguments `(data, 0, 0)` you will see it hit the `if`, fail, and return (displaying locals before the return will show `high=0` `low=0` of course, the function's local variables). Once that function has returned you'll be in its parent's stack frame, and displaying the locals at that point will show `low=0` `high=1` (the values of the parent's local variables). It was never incremented, you're just looking at a different `high`.